# Hidden element have focusable content issue

Tags: html, content-management-system

I am an entry level content management system editor and i am working on some of the issues on our website. I ran into this issue and i couldnt figure out how to fix it. If anybody is kind enough to give me a suggestion on how to fix it that would be much appreciated.
[image: screenshot]

I didn't try anything yet

Comment: Please post code as code (or at the very least as text) instead of photographs of code, since they're inaccessible and of no use whatsoever in recreating, or reproducing, your problem. Please read both "*[mcve]*" and "*[ask]*" guidelines. You may well benefit from taking the [tour]. Incidentally, "*trying nothing*" is not a strategy wet recommend, instead try researching (where possible), and attempt solutions, even if only in pseudo-code to demonstrate your thought process, and what might representa solution.

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of one of these solutions :

1- on CSS, in the container add:  display : none; or visibility: hidden;
2- using Javascript add attribute (tabindex="-1") to all the elements inside the container.